# XSS filtering on output... is that OK?

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss

I'm planning to run XSS filtering on output *only* so no matter what I still have the original data.

I'm using parameterized queries so I guess I'm immune against SQL injections.

What do you guys think of this approach?

Comment: I think it's great, but maybe you should turn this into more of a specific question. What do you guys think is not a question, try to address what you're worried about at least. It sounds like you may be on the right path.

Comment: @Madmartigan I wish I can be more specific but I'm just afraid I'm missing something crucial that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> XSS filtering on output… is that OK?

Yes.

> I'm using parameterized queries so I guess I'm immune against SQL injections.

Not entirely. See [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587) for the details